# Error in launching a website in IE browser using Selenium testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am failing in launching Google on IE browser using testng. Please find the code below.

```
package Demoqa_Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Demoqa_Registration {

public WebDriver Driver;

@Test
public void Regis() 
{
    // Driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
    Driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    String strPageTitle = Driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Page Title:- "+strPageTitle);
    // Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle,actualTitle);
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Browser Opened");
}  // Lanching Google

@BeforeClass
public void Ready() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("*******************");
    System.out.println("launching IE browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\workspace\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
} // Launching IE browser

@AfterClass
public void Signout() {
    if(Driver!=null) {
        System.out.println("Closing IE browser");
        Driver.quit();
    } // After class
}

}
```

It is launching the IE and giving error as 'This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server'.

Can anybody help please? Thanks.

Comment: Your issue is related to the scope of a variable. I suggest that you learn that first before going any further: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Thank you Sir. It was very helpful. It was my mistake in the code. I found it and the program is executable now. Thank you so much.